# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} -n \mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}}$ where $Z$ is a random variable on $\Omega = (0,1)$

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables

Let $Z_n$ be a random variable given by $Z_n = -n \mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}}$ where $Z$ is another random variable on $\Omega = (0,1)$.

Calculate $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} Z_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} -n \mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}}$$

### My attempt:

I know I must somehow split/or relate $\mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}}$ with an inequality, but I do not know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### My (partial) solution

The problem above was underspecified. I forgot to add that $Z$ lives in the sample space $\Omega = (0,1)$. Hence we have $$  \lim_{n \to \infty} -n \mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}} \leq  \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{1}_{Z \geq 1 - \frac{1}{n}}  = 1_{Z \geq 1 } = 0 $$ since $-n$ is negative and the indicator function is always non-negative, and $\{ Z \geq 1 \} $ is the empty set. However, now I only have an upper bound for the limit.

Comment: What is random here ?

Comment: The notation is bad in this case since it's actually $Z$ which is random and $X$ is a deterministic function acting on $Z$... I should probably change the description to reflect that.

Comment: "$Z$ is a random variable on $\Omega=(0,1)$" doesn't imply that $Z<1$! You probably want to specify the range of $Z$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_n$ converges to $0$ on $\{Z<1\}$ and diverges to $-\infty$ on $\{Z\ge 1\}$. In particular, if $\mathsf{P}(Z<1)=1$, then $Z_n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the proof for your first statement: $Z_n$ converges to 0 on $\{Z < 1\}$ ? Is it  something like: if we restrict the set of samples on which we evaluate $Z_n$ to the samples in $\{ Z < 1 \}$ then $Z_n$ is 0 because the indicator variable evaluates to 0 for large enough $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it means that for all $\omega\in\Omega$ s.t. $Z(\omega)<1$, $Z_n(\omega)\to 0$ because the indicator becomes $0$ eventually.